# Argument invalid when using cat to read a character device driver

Tags: c, kernel, debian, driver, linux-device-driver

When I try to read a char device using:

```
cat /dev/fifodev
```

I receive the next message from the terminal

```
cat: /dev/fifodev: Invalid argument.
```

I have created the file and gaven it the permissions like this

```
sudo mknod /dev/fifodev c 251 0
sudo chmod 666 /dev/fifodev
```

The code of my driver is:

```
/* 
 * Called when a process, which already opened the dev file, attempts to
 * read from it.
 */
static ssize_t device_read(struct file *filp,   /* see include/linux/fs.h   */
               char *buffer,    /* buffer to fill with data */
               size_t length,   /* length of the buffer     */
               loff_t * offset)
{
    char aux[BUF_LEN];

    printk(KERN_ALERT "Entering into device_read");

    if (size_cbuffer_t(buf)<length){
        return -EINVAL;
    }   

    remove_items_cbuffer_t (buf,aux, length);
    copy_to_user(buffer, aux, length);


    printk(KERN_ALERT "Getting out from device_read");

    return length;
}
```

What problem do I have here? Why can't I use cat with the /dev/fifodev file?

Comment: I've been testing and  the fail is that the program enters in `if (size_cbuffer_t(buf)<length)` but i do not know how to read n characters

Comment: i believe that issue is related with the way in that "cat" works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the function prototype buffer should be mentioned as __user to specify it as userspace pointer.
Return of the read method is length of the string read. This functions keeps getting recalled until it returns zero.
I think following code will work.

```
    static ssize_t device_read(struct file *filp,   /* see include/linux/fs.h   */
               char __user *buffer,    /* buffer to fill with data */
               size_t length,   /* length of the buffer     */
               loff_t * offset)
{
    char aux[BUF_LEN];
    int byte_to_read,maxbyte;   
    printk(KERN_ALERT "Entering into device_read");
    /*
    if (size_cbuffer_t(buf)<length){
        return -EINVAL;
    }   
    */
    maxbyte=strlen(buf) - *offset; //considering buf is the pointer where you have data to copy to buffer(userspace)
    byte_to_read=maxbyte>length?length:maxbyte;
    if(byte_to_read==0)
    {
        printk(KERN_ALERT "Allready Read\n");
        return 0;
    }
    aux=buf;//as in your code AUX doesn't have anything. i'm supposing you want to copy data to this from buf and then use copy_to_user
    remove_items_cbuffer_t (buf,aux, length); //i have no idea why you have used this but i'm sure this wont create any problem
    copy_to_user(buffer, aux, length); //this will copy your data to userspace
        

    printk(KERN_ALERT "Getting out from device_read");

    return length;
}
```

Comment: Ok, my fail, i haven't explained: buf is a circular FIFO buffer, `remove_items_cbuffer_t (buf,aux, length);` fills the variable aux with the content i want to copy to the user, deleting it from the FIFO buffer. so buf has a number of bytes and `size_cbuffer_t(buf)` returns the number of characters that the buffer keeps, so remove

Comment: according to your comment, you just need to comment out line `aux=buf;`
Most probable reason of your problem is that normally value of length is 32768. And length of your buf is smaller and according to your if statement it's returning -EINVAL.

Correct length checking is as shown in code above `maxbyte=strlen(buf) - *offset` and update offset after reading.
Hope removing `aux =buf;` from above code will make function work.

Answer (score 2):

Per your comment, the issue you're running into appears to be that your application is requesting to read data into a buffer that is larger than you have data to fill.

You will need to calculate the appropriate amount of data to copy (e.g, the smaller value of `length` and `size_cbuffer_t(buf)`), and use that value in the place of `length`.